# Fillable PDF / Task list for HR (centralized forms)

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I'm a University student working on a senior project for a nearby city. They've recently made the move to sharepoint for their intranet and we've been assigned to help with a smaller part of their larger project (The entire move to a sharepoint intranet has been an ongoing project that has been passed onto next semester's class).

Scope:
Create fillable PDFs to start the migration to a (mostly) paperless system.

Accessible to HR so they can view what has and has not been completed by the employee (typically new hires that has a load of forms to fill out such as W-4, benefits, etc.)

Technicals:
They've only asked us for the very basics - creating the forms so that the new employees can fill out the PDFs and have the files available in a personal file that HR can later view. However, we're not sure what to use.

Questions:
1) What PDF manager should we use (paid / free)? Infopath was originally our first choice but further researched showed its already EOL and actually creates non-standardized versions of PDFs.

2) How do we go about creating a personalized area which the new employees can "store" the forms they've completed? We know designer will allow us to create workflows but are not sure what is the proper way to start.

3) Would it be possible to create a checklist of sorts for HR to easily see what is completed versus manually going into and checking the files?

Any help would be appreciated. We're really struggling to get started and have been going in circles just researching what tools and steps are the correct ones.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check PDF Share Forms products : http://www.pdfshareforms.com/

Full disclaimer: I work for PDF Share Forms and you mentioned that you don't mind paid solutions. It seems that your case can totally be covered with our product.

They allow reusing existing PDF forms as templates, so you don't have to start from scratch if you already have some forms laying around that need to be transferred. Basically, you map form fields to SharePoint document library columns and the data is synchronized between them on submission. With a script you can write form data to SP list. Submitter's name will be associated with form names and the HR will be able to see how many forms been complete by that particular person.