# use the prebulit fillable pdf forms in the online sherpoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, pdf

I have a lot of complicated pdf forms and would like to use these forms in the sharepoint instead of creating them. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check this: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/237948/fillable-pdf-task-list-for-hr-centralized-forms

Answer (score 0):

Did you migrate the SharePoint on-premise to SharePoint online?

If so, I am afraid the pdf form cannot work in SharePoint online.

We can use InfoPath form and PowerApps form in SharePoint online.

More references:

[How to migrate from SharePoint On-Premises to SharePoint Online using the SharePoint Migration Tool.](https://www.manageengine.com/sharepoint-management-reporting/kb/how-to-migrate-sharepoint-on-premises-to-online.html)

[Using the SharePoint Migration Tool.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/how-to-use-the-sharepoint-migration-tool)